# Why do I need the Init function in my Controller?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am new to PHP and I have a few questions that follows:

Do I need the init function or can I do the job (whatever I need to do in my code) without the init function?

I am saying this because the NetBeans "kinda" created/added automatically the init() function in my project.

In my code I am suppose to create the CRUD functionality in it.

If I don't use it what's the problems I might have and the downsides?

Answer (score 4):

As the [official docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.action.html#zend.controller.action.prepostdispatch) would say:

> The init() method is primarily intended for extending the constructor. Typically, your constructor should simply set object state, and not perform much logic. This might include initializing resources used in the controller (such as models, configuration objects, etc.), or assigning values retrieved from the front controller, bootstrap, or a registry.

You can have controllers that don't override the init() method, but it will be called under the sheets anyways.

Comment: basically , `init()` is the method, which in framework-less environment you would execute when creating element through factory.

Answer (score 2):

If you are new to PHP, *do not start by using a framework*. Instead you should learn the language itself.

There is nothing significant about `init()` function. It is not a requirement for classes in PHP. Hell .. even `__construct()` is not mandatory in PHP.

That said, Zend Framework executes it right after the controller is created. It is required if you are using ZF.
You can read more about it [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.action.html#zend.controller.action.initialization).

Comment: I think that, in some cases, people that don't have all of that intimal relation with the language itself can suit quite confortable on working with a framework that abstracts the core stuff. Zend Framework may not be one of those cases, since it is one of the most complex frameworks out there; but still, that's one of the points of abstraction and high-level programming.

Comment: @drgomesp , in my experience, it always ends horribly. Case'n'point: "jquert programmers". People who haven't spent even an hour in learning native javascript but consider themselves professionals. And create code that will make your eyes bleed and your browser to choke.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Big Thanks for all of you.

Comment: I totally agree, and personally I have to deal with this kinda stuff every day. At the end of the day, it always comes to whether the guy behind the monitor knows how the high-level works under the sheets. But still, frameworks are supposed to make our life easier in many points, this being one of them.

Answer (score 1):

`init()` in Zend_Framework for most practical purposes is where you would put code that you need to affect all of the actions in that controller.(at least to test against all of the actions).

For example I often use the init() method to set up the the flashmessenger helper and to set the session namespace I want to be used.:

```
public function init() {

        if ($this->_helper->FlashMessenger->hasMessages()) {
            $this->view->messages = $this->_helper->FlashMessenger->getMessages();
        }
        //set the session namespace to property for easier access
        $this->_session  = new Zend_Session_Namespace('location');

    }
```

Also Netbeans did not make this method or the controller, Zend_Tool made the controller and the methods utilizing the interface that Netbeans provided. That's why in your PHP settings for Netbeans you have to provide the path to the ZF.bat file and click the register provider button if you change your ZF install.

One more thing...Be aware that there more methods available to the controller that provide hooks into different parts of the dispatch cycle. You may not need them very often but you need to know they are there.

Answer (score 0):

Simply its a constructor for that class(controller)...

```
init(){
$this->a = 1; //If we set something like this in the init
}

public function fooAction(){
echo $this->a; //1
}
public function barAction(){
echo $this->a; //1
}
```

ie the variables,objects..that is initialised in init will be available to all the actions in that controller